# DAX Formula Issue

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax

This DAX formula issue is frustrating me to no end so I appreciate any help or another way to look at this.

Both of these formulas calculate the same value and that's been confirmed so don't worry about what the LY_Key actually equals. BUT the one with Variables removes the ability to drill down into separate years in the same table. My problem really exists when using weeks, but it's slightly easier to understand using these tables.

Can you see a difference between these 2 formulas that would remove a drilldown capability? Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
---Original
Net Sales Trailing 3 Periods LY:= 
CALCULATE (
    factSales[Net Sales], 
    ALL(dimDate),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'dimPeriod' ), 
        'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey] <= MAX ( 'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey] ) - 14
        && 'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey] >= MAX ( 'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey] ) - 16
    )
)

---With Variables
Net Sales Trailing 3 Periods LY:= 

VAR 
    LY_FPW = MAX('dimPeriod'[YYYYFP]) - 100

VAR
    LY_Key = MAXX(FILTER('dimPeriod', 'dimPeriod'[YYYYFP] = LY_FPW), 'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey])

RETURN
CALCULATE (
    factSales[Net Sales], 
    ALL(dimDate),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'dimPeriod' ), 
        'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey] <= LY_Key - 1
        && 'dimPeriod'[PeriodKey] >= LY_Key - 3
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `PeriodKey` and `YYYFP` are and how they're related?

Comment: @AlexisOlson So YYYYFP is Fiscal Year and Fiscal Period in integer format. Fiscal Period is not exactly month but you could think of it the same way. For today's date, that value is 201808. Each Fiscal Period has a unique PeriodKey. So if 201808 is 40, then 201807 would be 39.